# Views to Display Nearby nodes according to user current location(latitued/longitute)GPS

Tags: views, javascript

I have Content type named Restaurant, When creating restaurant nodes I am imputing the Latitude/Longitude  using the GEOFIELD  module.

I have managed to Display all the restaurants in One Map using Views, Leaflet and leaflet Markercluster modules, you can see the attached screenshot.

My task now is to create a page named Nearby, where all restaurants near to user's current location(Latitude/Longitude) will be displayed, let say restaurant within 2km from the current users location.

To get the current user location, A prompt will appear on his/her browser asking them to share their location this is more specific for anonymous users.

I believe there must be a way to accomplish this task using Views or custom module.

Please Guide me step by step on how to make it happen.

any help will be highly appreciated. [image]

Answer (score 3):

Having messed with many Drupal mapping modules, I've found [IP Geolocation Views & Maps](https://www.drupal.org/project/ip_geoloc) to be the best overall helper (along with Leaflet, which I love). Give it a shot! It has lots of options, supports lots of maps, has geolocation stuff built in, marker clustering and some other stuff.

Comment: Thank you @scotself,  i will give a try as you suggested and Give u feedback.